# ¿cómo recorrer todo un foreach y retornar a una condición en vez de procesar esta en cada iteración?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

tengo una serie de procesos que manejan artículos en un almacén, ahora, el problema es que si el artículo está pendiente en una operación de ajuste de inventario no debería dejar procesar una compra/venta.

Mi intención es recorrer los artículos de una venta, verificar si hay alguno pendiente en un ajuste de stock y de ser así, no dejar procesar la operación hasta que el ajuste no sea aprobado/rechazado, pero no lo estoy logrando, ya que no sé cómo recorrer todo antes de procesar una condición.

Por ahora tengo:

```
    @foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
            @if ($detalleventa->articulo->ajusinv == 'y')           
                 <a class="jsgrid-button btn btn-warning">
                    Ajuste pendiente <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                 </a>
                 @break                               
            @else
                 <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('cambio.estado.ventas', $venta) }}"
                    title="Aprobar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                 </a>
                 <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" href="{{ route('cambio.rechazado.ventas', $venta) }}"
                    title="Rechazar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
                 </a>
           @endif
    @endforeach
```

Pero me está repitiendo los botones de aprobar y rechazar de la siguiente forma:

[image: botones repetidos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mi solución fue utilizar un contador que subiera cada que la condición se cumplía para luego hacer el `if` según el número que tuviera.

```
@php($count=0)
@foreach ($venta->detalleventas as $detalleventa)
    @if ($detalleventa->articulo->ajusinv == 'y')           
        @php($count++)
    @endif
@endforeach
@if ($count >= 1)           
    <a class="jsgrid-button btn btn-warning">
        Ajuste pendiente <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    </a>
    @break                               
@else
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('cambio.estado.ventas', $venta) }}"
        title="Aprobar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" href="{{ route('cambio.rechazado.ventas', $venta) }}"
        title="Rechazar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
    </a>
@endif
```